# onChangeText + setState not updating object value with deep merge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update my component's state by setting its state, but even after the onChangeText is triggered, my text isn't updating.

```
export default class Register extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

             newUser: {
                id: "",
                first_name: "Tom",
                last_name: "",
                email: "",
                age: 0,
                gender: "",
                classification: "",
                major: "",
                interest_tags: new Set()
            }

        }
    }

    updateUser = (text) =>{

    }
    render() {

        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.welcome}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Enter your information below:</Text>
                    </View>
                <View style={styles.inputView}>
                    <TextInput
                                style={styles.inputText}
                                placeholder='First Name'
                                placeholderTextColor='#34415e'
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
                                    ...this.state.newUser,
                                    first_name: text
                                    }), () => {console.log(this.state.newUser.first_name)}}

                    />

                </View>
```

No matter if I put the callback in the updateUser function or in the render function, I cannot update the first_name value of Tom. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
      newUser : {
         ...this.state.newUser,
         first_name: text,
      }
}), () => {console.log(this.state.newUser.first_name)}
```

Comment: This gives me the same output as before - my default first_name is still being shown, despite the text changing

Answer (score 0):

> "Use the inspector, Luke!"
>   ~ Obi Wan Reactnobi

On your `setState` call, you are merging both the contents of `newUser` as well as `first_name` into the state itself, not the `newUser` field of the state. So you're ending up with the following data in the state after updating it:

```js
{
  newUser: { /* the initial value*/ },

  // all the other proprerties inside `newUser`, such as
  email: "",
  age: 0,

  // then the key you merged into the state explicitly:
  first_name: "whatever the user typed"
}
```

You probably meant to write it like this (remember that `setState` is already a shallow merge, so only `newUser` will be updated, if you have more values in your state object):

```js
this.setState({
  newUser: {
    ...this.state.newUser,
    first_name: text
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm still facing the same unchanged text as before, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Where is it unchanged?

Comment: When I'm trying to show the newUser's updated first_name, it's still "Tom" when text is entered, even after using your suggestion @Kroltan. Is there a way to do avoid the shallow merge and actually change the object's value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must update state just with root object

you can not update state like that

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
                            ...this.state.newUser,
                            first_name: text
                            }), () => {console.log(this.state.newUser.first_name)}}
```

Let me give you my custom function for this.

```
updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
return {
    ...oldObject,
    ...updatedProperties
};};
```

you can use like this

```
 onChangeText={(text) => {
       let updatedFormElement ;
        updatedFormElement = this.updateObject(this.state.newUser, {
            first_name: text
        });
        this.setState({ newUser: updatedFormElement });
    }}
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! Would you mind explaining this a bit further? @Hasan

Comment: The fundamental idea of the object spread operator is to create a new plain object using the own properties of an existing object. So {...obj} creates a new object with the same properties and values as obj. For plain old JavaScript objects, you're essentially creating a copy of obj.
You must copy oldstate obj and new properties and merge them.